# parse pdf and identify page a phrase is on

Tags: pdf, parsing

I want to programmatically parse a pdf file, look for certain phrases and find out the page number that each phrase is on. Is this possible (I understand that pdf is not like a text file)? Is so, are there libraries out there that can help?

Comment: which language and platform are you trying to work on?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tika, which you can find at the [Apache Lucene project](http://lucene.apache.org), includes PDFBox, which will pull out the text where you can work with it.